# Calculate area for each polygon in R

Tags: shapefile, r, area

I am working with a shapefile that has many polygons.

How do I add one more field named "area_sqkm" and calculate area for each polygon in the shapefile?

Comment: What libraries do you have installed and what have you tried?

Comment: rgeos::gArea(x,byid=TRUE)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 30):

You can do

```
library(raster)
x <- shapefile('file.shp')
crs(x)
x$area_sqkm <- area(x) / 1000000
```

Or with `terra`

```
library(terra)
x <- vect('file.shp')
x$area_sqkm <- expanse(x) / 1000000
```

That works for both an angular CRS (longitude/latitude) and for planar CRSs. It is generally best to use a longitude/latitude CRS to compute area a planar CRS can distort size with a lot (How much? It depends on the CRS and on the location and extent of your spatial data).

Comment: is `raster::area()` with unprojected data more accurate than `rgeos::gArea()` with projected data?

Comment: It can be. Because projections distort. If the inter-node distance of the polygon is high, projection can distort the area further (see the `geosphere` vignette).

Comment: For other readers: This returns a numeric vector equal to the number of polygons (it looked to me as if it might be just for one polygon at a time)